# janomeがインポートできない

Tags: python

anacondaにjanomeをインストールしました
pycharmでもjanomeが表示されているのですが、プログラムを書くとエラーが出ます
pycharm上でもjanomeのパッケージをインストールするようにするのですができないとでます。使用している環境を誤っていないので原因がわからないです。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

左下のウィンドウに書いてあるPythonインタプリタの設定名と、上の画面のプロジェクトペインに書いてあるPythonインタプリタの名前が明らかに違っています。
上の画面のプロジェクトで設定を開いて、Project Interpreterに左下のウィンドウに書いてあるPythonインタプリタを選んでください。